# Storing Employee Accounts

Tags: mysql

I have a `Accounts` table in `MainDatabase` with the following columns:

```
AccountID | Username | Password | AccountDatabase
```

And `AccountDetails` table for `SpecificDatabase` *(`SpecificDatabase` will be based on the name the employer entered, so it will be dynamic)*:

```
AccountID | FirstName | LastName | AccountAccess
```

So every time a new employer registers, his inputs will be  saved in `MainDatabase`, and simultaneously creating a `SpecificDatabase` of his own. The problem I am facing is whether the employees for a specific employer will also be saved in the `MainDatabase` or in the `SpecificDatabase`.

If I saved the employees in the `MainDatabase`, I don't have to create a "token" to know what `SpecificDatabase` the employee belongs to, but `MainDatabase.Accounts` would end up having many rows. And if I saved the employees in its own `SpecificDatabase`, I would need to create a "token" in their login details, but maintenance for the `SpecificDatabase` will be easy *(ex. Employer expires, deletion will be easy)*.

**TL;DR**

What would be the most efficient way to store employee accounts, in the main database or in its employer's database?

Comment: A database rule is not to have any redundant data.

Comment: @RickJames What do you mean by redundant data?

Comment: I wouldn't store an employers employees in the main database, because of security considerations.

Comment: @hot2use So I guess I will be needing a token to determine what database that employee belongs to, or is there another for that?

Comment: E.g. An employer logs in to the (web-) application and is assigned an id from the main database. Any other request from said session is performed with a separate connection that access the other database.